# Howto Use musicbrainz performer tag

Tags: python, mp3, musicbrainz

I am working with MusicBrainz Picard Version: 1.2. If a particular track has vocals performer I would like to copy that field to the artist tag.

```
e.g. 

[https://musicbrainz.org/release/b251f5c0-4a41-40be-9d0d-68fdcecac317][1]

Track 1 "Khallas" I would like to copy 
vocals:
    Asha Bhosle, Sapna Awasthi, Sudesh Bhonsle 
To the artist tag.
```

**what is the best way to achive this python plugin or tagger script.
how should I access the vocals tag in tagger script**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use both the [copymerge](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting#.24copymerge.28new.2Cold.29) and [performer](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting#.24performer.28pattern.3D.22.22.2Cjoin.3D.22.2C_.22.29) scripting functions to achieve that. Under Options -> Options -> Advanced -> Scripting, insert

```
$set(_performers,$performer(vocal))
$copymerge(artist,_performers)
```

This will first extract all vocal performers (including choir vocals, spoken vocals, etc.) to a tag called `_performers` (this one will not get written to your files because its name is prefixed with an underscore) and then append all values in that tag to the regular `artist` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried the above snippet but for some reason $performer(vocal) is not working.
The above code only populates what's present in artist tag. do i need to define _performers somewhere first ?

Comment: If it's not working you most likely need to check Options -> Options -> Metadata -> Use track relationships.

Answer (score 0):

```
$copymerge(artist,performer:vocals)
```

This will directly merge vocal performers with artist without any duplicates.